# Get Text from a page inside another master page asp.net

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a asp.net page called `default.aspx` which has a masterpage called `ParentMaster`.

I am having another page called `info.aspx` which has a masterpage called `InforMaster`.

I am rendering the `info.aspx` inside a `iframe` located in the `default.aspx`.

I want to get the text of a literal which is present in the `ParentMaster` inside the `info.aspx`.

Below is the pictorial representation of my pages.

[image: Page layout]

I tried using the

`string infoCode = Page.master.FindControl("ltInfoCode").ToString()`

but its not working.

Is there a way to get the text from the masterpage to another page which also have a master page?

Comment: You cannot access a control inside a iframe. Maybe, you can do this using session storage

Comment: @CemŞengezer we can access it... Check below my provided code line

Comment: n number of master page can also be access by n number of control in sub frame..

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to access controls in Main Master page from content page in Nested Master Page..

```
string infocode = ((Literal)this.Master.Master.FindControl("ltInfoCode")).Text;
```

OR
 `Literal litInfoCode =  this.Master.Master.FindControl("ltInfoCode") as Literal;`

OR
`Literal litInfoCode =  (Literal)this.Master.Master.FindControl("ltInfoCode");`

Comment: Hi Shirish, The code will produce object reference not set to an instance error as its not able to find the control from Master.Master

Comment: For more reference u can check this link also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062217/how-to-access-controls-in-main-master-page-from-content-page-in-nested-master-pa